# Wpf Xaml view not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, updating

I have a splash screen that is supposed to show the loading process as the program starts up. I cannot get the text in the label to update as components are loaded.

From the main start-up program.cs I call the run() method in the splash screen controller.

```
startUpSplash.Run();
```

Here is the controller. This shows the splash screen with the label "Initializing..."

```
 public class StartUpSplashController
{
    public StartUpSplashViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    private StartUpSplashView starUpSplashWindow = new StartUpSplashView();
    private delegate void UIDelegate();
    public void Run()
    {
        InitializeViewModel();

        ViewModel.StatusMessage = "Initializing...";

        starUpSplashWindow.DataContext = ViewModel;
        starUpSplashWindow.Show();
    }



    public void UpdateStatus(string statusMessage)
    {
        starUpSplashWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UIDelegate(delegate { ViewModel.StatusMessage = statusMessage; }));
        //ViewModel.StatusMessage = statusMessage;
    }

    public void End()
    {
        starUpSplashWindow.Close();
        starUpSplashWindow.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private void InitializeViewModel()
    {
        ViewModel = new StartUpSplashViewModel(starUpSplashWindow);
        ViewModel.Controller = this;
    }
}
```

Then from the main program.cs as different things are happening I call this UpdateStatus method also in the splash controller. This is meant to update the label to show all the different thing that are happening.

This is the Xaml for the lbl that is supposed to be getting updated.

```
 <Label Content="{Binding Path=StatusMessage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger= PropertyChanged}"  />
```

The label is  not updating when the UpdateStatus method is called. One strange thing I noticed was that if I did a

```
startupSplash.UpdateStatus("something");
```

and then

```
Messagebox.show("something");
```

The splash screen shows the updated label after the messagebox has popped up.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

UPDATE 2: Here is the View Model

```
public class StartUpSplashViewModel : ViewModel<IView>
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public StartUpSplashViewModel(StartUpSplashView view)
        : base(view)
    {
    }

    public StartUpSplashController Controller { get; set; }

    private string _statusMessage;
    public string StatusMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return _statusMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_statusMessage == value)
                return;

            _statusMessage = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(s => s.StatusMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your ViewModel?

Comment: Thanks Henk, @Vijay: i have edited my question to show the viewModel. I try trigger the PropertyChanged event as shown. Is this wrong?

Comment: @TobyHolland Don't call starUpSplashWindow.InvalidateVisual(); and see what happens, not sure if that is causing the UI update to not occur.

Comment: @Aaron McIver - Unfortunately that is a new addition to try make it work. It didn't work without either

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks Henk, care to explain why?

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside your UpdateStatus() method and check whether the DataContext of starUpSplashWindow and Label is valid and not null..!!

Comment: This article says something about using DoEvents which might get you started and understand why Splash UI doesnt update: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFsplashscreen.aspx This article also has a sample demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up solving this.

I added another method to the splashScreenController and called it from within UpdateStatus after setting the ViewModel.Status message.

```
 [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    public void DoEvents()
    {
        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }

    public object ExitFrame(object f)
    {
        ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting the update on the splash window's running UI thread? You can use the Dispatcher.Invoke method to do so. First, you have to declare a delegate:

```
private delegate void UIDelegate();
```

Then you use that delegate in a Dispatcher:

```
starUpSplashWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UIDelegate(delegate
{
    ViewModel.StatusMessage = statusMessage;
}));
```

That'll invoke the update on the thread running the UI and that usually ensures the UI updates appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it might be what I need. Do I declare the delegate in the controller and then put the dispatcher inside the UpdateStatus method?

Comment: I *think* so. It's not entirely clear from your example, but that looks right.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the controller and the delegate you suggested. It is still not updating, can you see anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding the starUpSplashWindow.InvalidateVisual(); in the dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks again Jacob, I have tried that. Frustratingly still does not update the UI

Comment: Well crap. Got me stumped, then. I think I'd need the whole project to poke at from here... :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work as I have not tried but hoping it would work, please give it a try:

Create a `RefreshDelegate` and `Refresh` method inside the SplashWindow.xaml.cs View file as follows:

```
// To Refresh the UI immediately
private delegate void RefreshDelegate();
private static void Refresh(DependencyObject obj)
{
    obj.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render,
        (RefreshDelegate)delegate { });
}
```

Modify your `UpdateStatus` method in Controller as follows:

```
public void UpdateStatus(string statusMessage)
{    
    ViewModel.StatusMessage = statusMessage;
    starUpSplashWindow.Refresh(starUpSplashWindow.statusLabel); //where statusLabel is the name of the Label
}
```